# PHP PDO extension not working on IIS

Tags: php, iis, pdo

I have a script which uses __autoload() to load classes (stupid, I know, this is old code I used to use for fun / testing), and it seems to be trying to autoload PDO. This leads me to believe that it's not finding the PDO class it should be. I have checked php.ini and php_pdo.dll is enabled, along with php_pdo_mysql.dll, etc. The .dll files exist in "ext/" and I've restarted the web server numerous times.

I don't have much experience with IIS, but I've never had this issue on Linux, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: PDO is not in `phpinfo()`. I know it's not loaded correctly, I'm trying to figure out why. Here is my php.ini file: [php.ini on Pasebin](http://pastebin.com/cjrmmPb3)

C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext is the extension directory, and listed as such in php.ini and `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Show us the output of `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Check `phpinfo()`. Listing the .dll in the .ini isn't enough to be "sure" it's loaded. If PDO isn't listed in the phpinfo() output, it's not loaded.

Comment: Just because you've modified php.ini and the dll is in the ext folder doesn't mean it's loaded. Is your extension folder defined? Are you relying on a PATH that's not defined?

Comment: you'll have only problems with IIS and php ( + frameworks ) so i would recomend ( if you can or if you have access ) to install wamp or xampp for windows.

Comment: @poelinca Do you have any evidence to back that up? AFAIK, PHP runs just fine on IIS, it's even available to install via WebMatrix

Comment: @Phil Brown, it took me 3 hours to proprely install php-unit, no htaccess for nice permalinks ( i know it can be achived but ... ), folder&file permissions ...

Comment: @poelinca What does PHPUnit (via pear I assume) have to do with IIS? You know `.htaccess` is an Apache convention, right?

Comment: Installing WampServer or XAMPP is not an option. I run XAMPP on my local laptop, but this is not my server, it's a friend's. He wants to run IIS, not XAMPP. As far as a business environment goes, IIS is preferred over XAMPP or WampServer as far as I know.

Comment: @John Rather than go the manual route, you could give [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/index) a try. It plays nice with IIS, has a great web UI admin dashboard and works great out of the box

Comment: Thanks Phil, I'll look into it.
Until then, any help is still appreciated.

Comment: @John where is php_pdo.dll file ? in you're ext folder ? next to php_mysql.dll or php_mbstring.dll ? allso at line 303 in you're paste you have 2 line breaks witch i don't think do any good ...

Comment: Someone posted an answer below about the line breaks, but they don't actually exist (as I told them before they deleted the question,) rather they were a mistake when pasting.

And also, as I said in the question "the .dll files exist in ext/", I have already checked that `php_pdo.dll` and `php_pdo_mysql_mysqlnd.dll` exist.

Comment: @John as a side note, the claim that IIS is preferred over Apache in a business environment is blatantly untrue. The vast majority of big, heavy-duty PHP-driven web sites runs on Linux/Apache. That's not to say IIS isn't a fine environment for this - there's nothing wrong with what you're doing. Just chiming in to point it's not the *only* professional option.

Comment: I didn't say over Apache, I said over XAMPP or WampServer.

Comment: Personally, I prefer LAMP (as in Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) over WampServer (a third-party compilation), XAMPP (a third-party compilation), or IIS (Microsoft's server stuff).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing I find odd is that you are specifying the extension in the `[PDO]` section.  I'm not aware of this kind of notation - my Windows php.ini doesn't do that. It could be that the line gets ignored because it gets interpreted as `PDO.extension` which doesn't make sense.

What happens if you move the `extension=php_pdo.dll` bit into the main body of the INI file (outside any  `[]` section)?

If that  doesn't change anything: 
Are you 100000% sure you are editing the correct php.ini?

With the extension specified in the file, PHP should either crash when you restart the server, or give you the PDO class.

Check `phpinfo()` to see which ini file is being used exactly.

Comment: According to phpinfo(): `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini`
This is what I'm currently editing.
I also commented out the [PHP_PDO] and the extensions, and moved them up to the main body, it still didn't work.

Comment: @John hmm, really strange. Can you try initializing `new PDO(....);` in a file that has no autoloading capability? Just to confirm 100% that PDO not loading is the problem?

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in C:\inetpub\robwolff.co.cc\test.php on line 3

Comment: @John okay, that is pretty clear. Weird. The last idea I have is to check the windows directory for a php.ini file. Maybe there's some weirdness that causes PHP to use that one, I vaguely remember that being standard behaviour in some situations. Other than that, I really don't know what this could be.

Comment: Even though phpinfo() tells me that it's not that php.ini being used?

Comment: @John yeah. It's a long shot and unlikely, but worth a try

Comment: Nope, I checked both C:\Windows and C:\Windows\system32

Comment: Even though it didn't work, this is probably the best answer. Thanks Pekka!

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you have done most/all of the following things but here is what I would do:

1 : Look into IIS error log and see if it reports any issues (i havent worked with IIS in a while but i am sure there is an error log file somewhere)

2 : Make sure other .dll files are being loaded by cross checking in phpinfo()

3 : Comment out all the extensions like php_mbstring.dll, gd2 etc and see if that reflects in the phpinfo(), then start enabling one by one.

4 : Delete all the sections at bottom and simply put the extensions in the dynamic extensions section of the ini. something like

```
extension=php_abc.dll
extension=php_xyz.dll
extension=php_123.dll
```

5 : I have always been a bit reluctant on having spaces in directory names, so i would copy the ext folder to the root of c somewhere for testing, maybe something like c:\phpexts

6 : I would take the same php.ini and create a similar environment in apache (same php version) and see if it works or conversely port a php.ini from Apache to IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening `cmd` and typing `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\bin\php -r ""`.

Do you get an error message? If yes, what?

Make sure you have the correct extension for the `Visual C++` version you're using with IIS.

If no, take that directory and move it to `C:\`. It might be related to the spaces in the path. Adjust your IIS configuration and try again.

Good luck!

Comment: php5ts.dll is missing, and I'm using some Microsoft support thing to try and fix that. If it works, you have my best answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem, check the permissions on the dll files, did the trick for me.

Comment: They seem to be fine. Full control for SYSTEM and Admins, Read+Execute for Users.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem just check the variable extension_dir inside [WebPIChanges]

Answer (score 0):

please look at this answer:
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34385738/6612054)
and in a conclusion you need to install php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll in your extensions.

you can download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=20098)